# Correct way to implement NestedRecyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I know this topic has been 'touched' alot of times, but I still haven't found the `correct` way of implementing recyclerview/s inside recyclerview.

My goal is to have a single vertical recyclerview as parent and multiple horizontal recyclerviews inside of it.

[image]

I found an implementation to this within this post answer:
[How do I layout nested RecyclerViews, while remaining performant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079438/how-do-i-layout-nested-recyclerviews-while-remaining-performant)

What it suggests is, inside parent recyclerview `onBindVH()` method call
`holder.setAdapter(childAdapter)`. 
Is this correct way? I think, this is not the best solution performance wise. Is there better solution to implement nested recyclerviews (explanations are welcome)?

Comment: try this.. https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter many things are handled performance wise.. its a sectioned recyclerview so set the child adapter horizontal layout manager...

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-handling-of-lists-rendererrecyclerviewadapter-part-2-3b18c8ea6f1b     and 
  https://medium.com/@mgn524/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7

Comment: I managed to cache views, but still, first drawing is slow and stutters alot.