# Which Recyclerview or ScrollView should I choose?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-scrollview

I created an activity with a `ListView`. That is a Friend `ListView`.

I wanna let it choose to add it to another `View`.

I don't know which `View` to choose is the best.  `Recyclerview` or `ScrollView`?

Like this

[image]

Comment: Recommend you to use `RecyclerView` for both. Just you need to set the direction `HORIZONTAL` for top layout and for the bottom `VERTICAL`.

Answer (score 3):

Basic difference between `RecyclerView` and `ListView` are the below.

`ListView` is simple to implement. Default Adapters available.
But `ViewHolder` pattern and finding views using ID's used to give slow performance.

Now in `RecyclerView` , the above problems are attended using [RecyclerView.ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder).
For `RecyclerView` adapter, this `ViewHolder` is mandatory. While comparing to list view this is kinda complex, but solves performance issues in `ListView`.

Difference `LayoutManagers` are available while using `RecyclerView`.

- [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager)
- [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager)
- [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager)

Major improvement of RecyclerView performance while comparing to ListView would be this  according to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

> The RecyclerView creates only as many view holders as are needed to
>   display the on-screen portion of the dynamic content, plus a few
>   extra. As the user scrolls through the list, the RecyclerView takes
>   the off-screen views and rebinds them to the data which is scrolling
>   onto the screen

**To sumup, RecyclerView is preferable than ListView (when UI is having same widgets repeating according to your data)**

---

---

Now when to use `ScrollView`:

Your UI elements may not show completely in small device screens. But in bigger screen sizes it may!
Elements may not be necessarily only list / grid. It can have combinations of any UI widgets.

Eg:- `TextViews` vertically , with `RadioButton` and `Button` at last for user action.

This cannot be included in `ListView`/ `RecyclerView` , now you can add `ScrollView` which will have a `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout` . Inside which all other elements can be added.

Now you can

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to user always RecyclerView and never a ListView. Use RecyclerView for element list and scrollview for static views.

Seeing your image Scrollview inside RecyclerView or ListView have problems with drag.

Use a vertical RecyclerView in all page and horizontal RecyclerView each row.

Comment: So my ListView has to change into a RecyclerView ?

Comment: In my opinion always.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use RecyclerView because you will load lots of images and if you use ScrollView eventually you will use so much memory. Also it is recommended to use RecyclerView when you have dynamic data. You can look the definition of the RecyclerView in the Android Documentation as follow

> RecyclerView  is a view for efficiently displaying large data sets by
>   providing a limited window of data items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested RecyclerView for creating such hierarchal view.
You can also checkout this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079438/how-do-i-layout-nested-recyclerviews-while-remaining-performant) for nested RecyclerView usage.

Also you can further read:

- [Android Recyclerview vs ListView with Viewholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525112/android-recyclerview-vs-listview-with-viewholder/31199564)
- [RecyclerView vs. ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview)
- [Should we use RecyclerView to replace ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview?rq=1)

I hope this helps.