# How can i create a RecyclerView inside of the another recyclerview's item?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I want to make recyclerview inside of the another recyclerview's item.,Please help me,Thankyou.

Comment: I have never tried this but there has got to be a better way. I feel like that would be incredibly inefficient.

Comment: What is the purpose of this ?

Comment: Its not an Rocket Science !! : ) You can dynamically add child recyclerview into parent recyclerview but first explain your requirement in details then we can help you to achieve your task..!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a recyclerView inside another recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569217/how-to-add-a-recyclerview-inside-another-recyclerview)

Comment: I want to display all comments and replies of the post like a facebook,But all comments and replies are in same page not in different activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

**- MainRecyclerView Item**

**item_post.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llItemPost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPostCname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Company Name"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_21ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:text="Post:-"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvPostSub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**- MainRecyclerView Adapter**

**PostAdapter.class**

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "PostAdapter";

    private PostSubAdapter postSubAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> yourSubArrayList;

    public PostAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, ArrayList<String> yourSubArrayList, Context mContext) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.yourSubArrayList = yourSubArrayList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_post, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.txtPostCname.setText(arrayList.get(i));

        viewHolder.rvPostSub.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        postSubAdapter = new PostSubAdapter(yourSubArrayList, mContext);
        viewHolder.rvPostSub.setAdapter(postSubAdapter);
        postSubAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerView rvPostSub;
        TextView txtPostCname;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtPostCname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostCname);
            rvPostSub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvPostSub);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

**- SubRecyclerView Item**

**item_post_sub.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:text="Post"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp" />

    <View
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/viewDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:background="@drawable/social_media_divider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**- SubRecyclerView Adapter**

**PostSubAdapter.class**

```
public class PostSubAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostSubAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    Context mContext;

    public PostSubAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, Context mContext) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_post_sub, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String post=arrayList.get(i).replace("\\n","\n");
        viewHolder.txtPost.setText(post);
        if(i==arrayList.size()-1)
        {
            viewHolder.viewDivider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtPost;
        View viewDivider;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtPost=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPost);
            viewDivider=itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewDivider);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In the bind view holder of 1st recyclerview use it like:

```
InnerRecyclerviewAdapter adapter=new InnerRecyclerviewAdapter(context,urlistArray);
holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

[For further guidance click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33096208/6874315)